# How can I make Dialog take 80% of the screen in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working with Material-UI Dialog and I want to make it take 80% of the screen.
Ideally, I want something like this.[image]

I am applying a margin to Dialog but it is not working as intended.

Answer (score 11):

For **older material-ui** versions like 0.20.0:

```
<Dialog
   title="Dialog With 80% Width"
   modal={true}
   contentStyle={{
      width: '80%',
      maxWidth: 'none',
   }}
   open={true}
>
   This dialog spans the 80% width of the screen.
</Dialog>
```

---

And in **material-ui V1** using these props may can help with your needs

```
fullWidth={true}
maxWidth = {'md'}
```

Here is [examples](https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/) and other [props](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/) for Dialog component, or in more advanced way you can take a look into [Dialog component code](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Dialog/Dialog.js) see what is happening there.

Answer (score 2):

The `paperFullWidth` css class of `Dialog` component might be helpful. The only condition for using this class is the `fullWidth` prop of `Dialog` component should be true. Below is a sample snippet

```
import React from "react";
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
  dialogCustomizedWidth: {
    'max-width': '80%'
  }
});

const DialogExample = ({ classes }) => (
  <Dialog
    open
    fullWidth
    classes={{ paperFullWidth: classes.dialogCustomizedWidth }}
  >
    I'm a Dialog with customized width.
  </Dialog>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(DialogExample);
```